# Reg ex: ^\\d+(\\,\\d+)*$ meaning?

Tags: javascript, regex

I came across this regular expression in java script `(^\\d+(\\,\\d+)*$)`.

this is matched with quantity. As I am not much aware of this topic, please help me with its meaning. Also, can we use **\d** instead of **\\d**, what is the difference between using single and double slashes? Thanks.

Comment: Paste the pattern at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) and study the explanation on the right.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really helped me.